# Send multipart form data thru HTTP POST request

Tags: java, forms, jsp, file-upload

I have a question regarding upload of files using multipart encoding. I have created following jsps.

upload.jsp contains a form thru which an input file will be uploaded
uploadAction.jsp contains code to extract the data and save it in server.

Even though I have specified enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag, it is showing the content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded in uploadAction.jsp
Can someone please explain what is wrong with the code and why content type is retained as multipart/form-data in uploadAction.jsp

upload.jsp

```
 <script>
function try1(){
        document.forms[0].action = "uploadAction.jsp";
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>

 <form id="attachmentUploadFormId1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                    <input type='file' id='attachmentFileNameId1' name='attachmentFileNam1e' size='50'>
                    <input class="inforFormButton" type='submit' id="attachmentUploadSumitId1" name="Attach" value="Attach" onclick="try1()" >
</form>
```

uploadAction.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Result</title>
</head>
<body>
 <br>
 <h2>File Upload Results</h2>
<br>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>

<%
String contentType = request.getContentType();
System.out.println("Content type is :: " +contentType);
if (contentType != null) {

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
System.out.println("stream: " + request.getInputStream());

int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
System.out.println("content length:" + Integer.toString(formDataLength));
/***rest of the code to process content****/
```

request.getContentType() in uploadAction.jsp is resulting in a value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of multipart/form-data. Please let me know why content type is not retained.

Comment: You can try setting document.forms[0].enctype = "multipart/form-data".

Comment: I have tried this also, but it is not working.